# How to draw cube, cuboid and pyramid

Tags: processing.js

I am using the following code to draw a cube.

```
// Re-creates the default perspective
size(100, 100, P3D);
noFill();
smooth();
float fov = PI/3.0;
fill(25, 210, 12);
float cameraZ = (height/2.0) / tan(fov/2.0);
perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 
            cameraZ/10.0, cameraZ*10.0);
translate(50, 50, 0);
rotateX(-PI/6);
rotateY(PI/3.5);
box(45);
```

The call to perspective method causes the cube to show up in dotted lines, how do I modify the code to get a solid line.

Are there any libraries on top of processing.js which provide a simple wrapper to build these 3D shapes.

Answer (score 1):

On a functional note, you'll want to format that code better:

```
void setup() {
  // Re-creates the default perspective
  size(100, 100, P3D);
  noFill();
  smooth();
  // use this if your animation is input-based,
  // so the browser doesn't hog the cpu.
  noLoop(); 
}

void draw() {
  float fov = PI/3.0;
  fill(25, 210, 12);
  float cameraZ = (height/2.0) / tan(fov/2.0);
  perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), 
              cameraZ/10.0, cameraZ*10.0);
  translate(50, 50, 0);
  rotateX(-PI/6);
  rotateY(PI/3.5);
  box(45);
}
```

But on a constructive note: this code works fine for me using processing.js 1.1.0 in Chrome 10 and Firefox 4. There are no dotted lines, just nice solid edges.